# Query that fetches all table names & column names in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve all table names and column names IN A SCHEMA. So if I am in schema `scott` it should only show all the tables present in `scott`.

And can the query below only retrieve the tables in a schema?

```
Select * from tab;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'SCOTT'
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_part.htm#i125539

Answer (score -1):

This query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Oracle does not have an `information_schema`